can't connect to Postgres database from jupyter Notebook using Psycopg2
I am trying to connect to a database in Postgres to insert data into my tables.
From Jupyter Notebook. I am using these commands:
# connect to the database
#url = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost:5432/citibike' 

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://localhost/citibike')
con = engine.connect()
df_date.to_sql('date_dim', con, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=10000)
stations.to_sql('stations', con, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=10000)
trip_demo.to_sql('trip_demo', con, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=10000)
df_weather.to_sql('weather', con, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=10000)
rides.to_sql('rides', con, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=10000)

con.close()`

But when I try to run the code I am getting this error:
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "rkb18" does not exist

I have checked my login details and all the details for host, database, username, port etc are correct.
rkb18 is my user name in the Windows hierarchy on my laptop, but I am not sure how this is involved with what I am trying to do here.
I am using Postbird as my interface to Postgres.
any help/advice would be appreciated.

Have you tried to create the engine using "engine = create_engine('postgresql://your_username:your_password@localhost:5432/citibike')" ?

This postgresql://localhost/citibike is not providing a username. When there is no username provided Postgres will use the OS username the program is  running as. Obviously rkb18 is not a Postgres user(role). In your connection string provide a Postgres username. This and a lot more is explained here libpq key owrds.
